# Добавление элемента в конец массива

Tags: массивы, c++

Есть динамически созданный и заполненный массив размерности 10. Как исключительно средствами C++ добавить в конец этого массива 11 элемент ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать новый массив размера 11 и скопировать поэлементно старый массив в новый. realloc и std::vector делают тоже самое, только вектор увеличивает размер нового в ~1.5-2 раза.

Comment: 1. Лучше работу доверять стандартным функциям и сводить количество вызовов функций к минимуму.
2. vector не просто так выделяет дополнительный объем памяти - он его резервирует для последующих возможных элементов, поскольку выделение памяти в куче - довольно дорогая операция.

Comment: Если фраза исключительно средствами С++ подразумевает возможность использования стандартной библиотеки(vector), то конечно изобретать велосипед нет смысла. realloc как вы писали средство языка C. Если библиотека запрещена(обучающая задача), то остается вариант с new/delete.

Answer (score 3):

Это смотря какой массив у тебя создан. Если std::vector, то всё просто. Он расширяется автоматически при добавлении элементов:

```
std::vector<int> vec(10);
//Заполняем...
vec.push_back(element11);
```

Если без контейнеров, то

```
int* array=new int[10];
//Заполняем...
int* newArray=new int[11];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) newArray[i]=array[i];
delete[] array;
array=newArray;
array[10]=element11;
```

Comment: Что-то не то, уважаемый @GLmonster.
 
delete[] array; 
array=newArray; ??????????
array[10]=element11; ??????????


Откуда у удаленного массива возьмется 11-ый элемент?

Comment: Всё то. Я копирую массивы, удаляю старый, старому указателю array присваиваю указатель на новый newArray. Теперь array указывает на новый массив.

Comment: Все правильно. Пардон.

Answer (score 2):

Либо STL (vector  и т.д.), либо средствами C (realloc). Насколько мне известно, С++ не предоставляет простых средств для изменения размера массива.

Comment: добавлю, что в C++ есть еще new и new[], которые, в отличие от realloc, вызывают деструкторы объектов